# Hide/disable buttons on flash player version 7 tool bar

Tags: adobe, embed, flash, object-tag

[image]how to hide little 'x' button on flash player through HTML object/embed tag ??

I tried

```
param name="showexit" value="0"
```

, but it did not do anything.

P.S when you hover on the 'x' button, it displays tooltip as 'exit'.

Comment: About which exit button are you speaking ?! I never heard about a such button in flash object embedded in a html page ! Could you explain more your problem with a screen shot ?

Comment: i need to hide 'cc' button as well. Can you please help me ?

Comment: And what's the player or the component that you are using in your project ?

Comment: adobe flash player 11.4....

Comment: I meant the player / component ( visible in the image ) that you have used in your flash project which has the gray bar with buttons. Is it an flvplayback component ?

Comment: OK, I see ! Forget my question, could you put your fla or a link to your page if it's visible online ? The fla is the source file of your flash project ( with the red icon ), you can upload it to any free hosting / sharing service ( like google drive, mega, filedropper.com, ... ).

Comment: @akmozo .. I finally figured it out...updated it in swf instead of doing it from HTML/Javascript. Thanks !